# how can I print a character vector in a way I can create another vector in R?

Tags: r, string, printing

I'm sorry for the question, I just didn't know how to google it.

let's say I have the following vector

```
names<-c("a","b","c")
> c("a","b","c")
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Now I want to print it so that I can assign the output to another vector and create the same object. Something like:

```
>otherKindOfPrint(names)
  c("a","b","c")
```

I need to do this because I copied something from a text and played with it for a while until I get to an analogous to "names". I can't tell R to copy something from an e-mail I got so I just want to write the values I got in the script so I can save it.

Thank you so much!,

Comment: definitely a candidate for [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `dput`

```
dput(names)

# c("a", "b", "c")
```